# Find Inverse Tangent?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, processing.js

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to use inverse tangent to find the angle in degrees between a line and the x axis on an elevated y. I don't see any command for it so I really need some help.

Comment: Do you mean arctanget?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`Math.atan()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan) function and then <s>`Math.toDegrees()`</s> multiply it by `180/Math.PI` to convert radians to degrees
Found the answer it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3449860/3029422)

## Later edit:

Here is an example of angle calculation between a `line` defined by 2 points (`A` and `B`) and the `X axis`.
The elevation of the second line (parallel with the X axis) is irrelevant since the angle stays the same.

```js
 /*
 * Calculates the angle between AB and the X axis
 * A and B are points (ax,ay) and (bx,by)
 */
function getAngleDeg(ax,ay,bx,by) {
  var angleRad = Math.atan((ay-by)/(ax-bx));
  var angleDeg = angleRad * 180 / Math.PI;
  
  return(angleDeg);
}

console.log(getAngleDeg(0,1,0,0));
```

Comment: what do I put into the atan? is it all 3 x's and y's

Comment: If a ratio is being used, it is better to use Math.atan2(y, x). It gets the correct quadrant and avoids possible division by zero problems.

Answer (score 2):

I found this short and simple:

```
const calculateAngle = (width, height) => Math.atan(width/height)/(Math.PI / 180) // Angle in degrees
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Math.atan` (outputs angle in radians) and some trigonometry.

Answer (score 0):

Questions like these are best answered by [the reference](http://web.archive.org/web/20181122222329/http://processingjs.org/reference/). I see a bunch of trigonometric functions there, including:

- [`acos()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20181122222329/http://processingjs.org/reference/acos_/)
- [`asin()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20181122222329/http://processingjs.org/reference/asin_/)
- [`atan()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20181122222329/http://processingjs.org/reference/atan_/)
- [`atan2()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20181122222329/http://processingjs.org/reference/atan2_/)
- [`cos()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20181122222329/http://processingjs.org/reference/cos_/)
- [`degrees()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20181122222329/http://processingjs.org/reference/degrees/)
- [`radians()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20181122222329/http://processingjs.org/reference/radians/)
- [`sin()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20181122222329/http://processingjs.org/reference/sin_/)
- [`tan()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20181122222329/http://processingjs.org/reference/tan/)

**Note:** As of Dec 5, 2018, the repository has been archived and processingjs.org redirects there.

> With the development of [p5js](https://p5js.org/) and the API advances in [Processing](https://processing.org/) itself, as well as Processing.js itself having been in maintenance mode for quite a few years now, this project has been archived as of December 2018.
>
> Processing.js would like to thank everyone who contributed over the years: it's been an amazing project! The code will still be available in read-only mode, no releases will be pulled from any of the places it was distributed through, but the last version is, and will forever be, [v1.6.6](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js/tree/v1.6.6).
>
> Thank you for your support, and happy coding (with newer solutions)!